# .filter() function creating loop in delete function - React

Tags: reactjs

I've got a 'list' component, which allows you to add an item to a state array, and then display it from the state afterwards. These list items can then be removed by the user afterwards (or should be able to).

There's four state props in this component:

- currentList: content in the input that's to be added to the list array
- setCurrentList: what's used to change the content in the input
- fullList: the full array list
- setFullList: used to add the currentList content to the array, and removed

I'm using .filter() to create a copy of the state array, and then set the state afterwards in this function:

```
const deleteFromList = (e) => {

        console.log("Delete button pressed")
        console.log(e)

        let fullList = props.fullListState
        let setFullList = props.setFullListState

        let filteredArray = fullList.filter(item => item)

        setFullList(filteredArray)
    }
```

However, every time I execute this function (i.e. when the delete button is pressed), it just creates a loop and the first two console.logs are just repeatedly done.

This is the full return function itself:

```
<>
            <label className="setup-jobs-label">{props.label}</label>
            <div className="setup-jobs-input-container">
                <input className="setup-jobs-alt-input" type="text" onChange={onChange} value={props.currentListState} />
                <button className="setup-jobs-add-button" onClick={addToList}>Add</button>
            </div>
            { props.fullListState === [] ? null : props.fullListState.map(x => {
                return <div className="setup-jobs-input-container" key={props.fullListState[x]}>
                    <p className="setup-jobs-input-paragraph">{x}</p>
                    <button className="setup-jobs-delete-button" onClick={deleteFromList(x)}>Delete</button>
                </div>
            }) }
        </>
```

The important bit is the bottom conditional render, which checks to see if the state array is empty, and if so, not display anything. If it isn't, then it returns null.

Any advice would be appreciated - not sure what I'm doing wrong in the filter function.

Comment: `props.fullListState === []` will always return false. `[] === []` will return false as their reference are different. prefer `props.fullListState.length === 0` to check if the array is empty

Comment: also if your intention is to create an exact copy of an array. `filter` works but is not really made for that purpose. prefer `const duplucateArray = [... fullList]`

Comment: Worth noting that filter AND spread operator create shallow copies (not deep copies) : if the iterable contains objects, the same objects are used in the result (same references), but you get a new array reference (original array is not mutated). So in this case you don't need to shallow copy your array with a spread operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `onClick` handler, you pass the result of the execution of `deleteFromList`, you should pass a reference to this function instead :

```
// note the '() =>' 
<button className="setup-jobs-delete-button" onClick={() => deleteFromList(x)}>Delete</button>
```

See https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html for more details about this.

Beside this, your filter logic does not seem right :

```
// this line only removes falsy values, but not the "e" values
let filteredArray = fullList.filter(item => item)

// you should implement something like this
let filteredArray = fullList.filter(item => [item is not "e"])
// this should work as we work on objects references
let filteredArray = fullList.filter(item => item !== e)
```

Comment: Yep, this solves the rendering issue. The filter itself isn't working unfortunately. There's something not quite right with it, but probably a separate question.

Comment: I edited my answer : your filtering seems broken, you should keep all values that are not the parameter ("e")